Excel data validation with related tables
I am struggling with a data validation using tables in Excel. I have two tables, one for "category" that has a list of categories, and a second table for 'types' that has a column / field 'category' that is related to the column / field 'category' in the categories table. This comes from a 1-to-many relationship in the data where each categories[category] can have multiple types[category] entries. The 'types' table has several other columns in it as well.
I am creating a data entry table 'tblData' for users to input new information, with two of the columns/fields in the data entry table using information from the 'categories' and 'types' related tables. The hope is to use data validation to control what the users can put into the columns / fields using drop-down lists.
The tblData[category] column / field has data validation that works and looks like this:
=IF(INDIRECT("tblData[@Type]")="",_Category,INDIRECT("NoList"))
You can see that I have created a name definition '_Category' that actually refers to the specific column in tblCategories. This works for getting the category values into the data validation drop-down, though I cannot achieve it without the helper defined name.
The problem now comes with the dependent drop-down for the column / field tblData[type] that depends on the value the user chooses in tblData[Category]. The data in the related table is normalised so that it looks like:
   Category 1  |  Type B
   Category 1  |  Type C
   Category 2  |  Type K
   Category 2  |  Type L

I cannot seem to find a way to get the filtered list of types based on category chosen by the user to work as a data validation. The following FILTER formula works perfectly in a worksheet and returns the exact data needed:
=FILTER(tblTypes[Type],tblTypes[Category]="Software")

I am using "Software" there only for example purposes.
How can I get the filtered data out of the normalised table into a data validation drop-down based on the users choice in tblData[Category]?
Any ideas?
Cheers
The Frog

This can be resolved in such way:

Create the Category/Type table as depicted.

Define the 'Categories' name.

Define names for types holding CTRL and selecting each category column one by one then command 'Create Names from Selection'.

Define data validation for categories.

Define data validation for types.


